Excel Power Query Issue
I have an extremely large dataset to analyze, the file can be slimmed down by using a list of identifiers, which I created a table and converted it to a list.
Then the large dataset, I bring in and use the following query, but am getting an expression error.
Expression.Error: The field 'SSN' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
Column1=D202402M
Column2=
My end result is the filter out and only return where column SSN of the large dataset matches to the PA_SSN_LIST.
Below is my entire query, where PA_SSN_LIST is the name of the list as well as the column name.
let
    Buffered.List = List.Buffer(PA_SSN_LIST),
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("H:\Analysis\State Data Match\State Programs\WI_StateDataMatch.TXT"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "Raw Data"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Column2"}),
    AddedRecordType = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Record Type", each Text.Start([Raw Data],1)),
    AddedSSN = Table.AddColumn(AddedRecordType, "SSN", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],1,9)),
    AddedStatePassBack = Table.AddColumn(AddedSSN, "State Pass Back", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],10,10)),
    AddedFirstName = Table.AddColumn(AddedStatePassBack, "First Name", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],40,16)),
    AddedLastName = Table.AddColumn(AddedFirstName, "Last Name", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],20,20)),
    AddedCasePassBack = Table.AddColumn(AddedLastName, "Case Pass Back", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],56,15)),
    AddedFIPSCode = Table.AddColumn(AddedCasePassBack, "FIPS Code", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],71,5)),
    AddedAdditionalPassBack = Table.AddColumn(AddedFIPSCode, "Additional Pass Back", each Text.Middle([Raw Data],76,23)),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"AddedSSN" , each List.Contains(Buffered.List,[SSN]))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

Any help is appreciated!
Code reformatted.  Issue I am having now, is that , all of the Add columns are not retaining after the filter rows occur, the only columns in the output is Record Type & SSN & Raw Data.  I need the rest of the Add columns to populate after the filter rows.

the  #"Filtered Rows"  is applied to the #"AddedSSN" step.  I assume it should apply to the immediate preceding step AddedAdditionalPassBack   Thats why things disappear.  So change Table.SelectRows(#"AddedSSN" , each to Table.SelectRows(AddedAdditionalPassBack , each to

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. The tag information should not be in the title at all, and the word "issue" is so vague you could just as well have said "blah blah". The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].
